# Why is the assumption $(dx)^2 = 0$ actually correct instead of just approximately correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume

Imagine dividing a sphere into concentric spherical shells of thickness $dr$ and inner radius $r$.

The volume of each shell is $$dV = \frac{4\pi}{3}  [ (r + dr)^3 - r^3]$$

Expand the cubic expressions, we get:

$$
(r + dr)^3 - r^3 = r^3 + dr^3 + 3r^2 dr + 3rdr^2 - r^3 = 3r^2dr + 3rdr^2 + dr^3
$$

Assuming that $dr^3 = 0$ and $rdr^2 = 0$, we get:

$$(r + dr)^3 -r^3= 3r^2dr$$
Thus, the volume of each shell is $dV = 4\pi r^2dr$.

If we integrate along the radius, then we get $$\int_0^R 4\pi r^2dr =  \frac43\pi R^3$$ This confirms that our analysis of the spherical shell volumes is correct. However, this analysis relies on the assumption that $dr^3 = 0$ and $rdr^2 = 0$. My question is why are these assumptions correct? If we assume those values are zero, shouldn't the final value just be approximately correct by an infinitesimal amount instead of being absolutely correct?

Comment: What is $dr$?  If you say “an infinitesimally small real number” then you're already cheating in some sense.  There are no infinitesimally small real numbers.  To make the analysis rigorous, look at Riemann sums of shells with small but finite thickness $\Delta r$ rather than just a single shell.  The terms which have  $\Delta r^2$ in them will tend to zero as $\Delta r \to 0$.

Comment: Infinitesimal amount means absolutely correct

Comment: This might not be a satisfying answer, but it's really just a formal thing, and it's all a bit more subtle than what is taught in a first multivariable calc course. In other words, $dx^2=0$ because thats how it's defined. In reality, $dx$ is a differential form, which lives in something called an exterior product. These exterior products are characterized by the fact that any two elements *anti-commute,* so $dx\ dy=-dy\ dx$. This is why the order of integration matters. Another consequence is that anything squares to zero, so $dx^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of $dr$ as a number, think of the manipulations you've used to get $dV=4\pi r^2dr$ as a shortcut for computing $\frac{dV}{dr}$ using the limit definition of the derivative: $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3r^2h+3rh^2+h^3}h=3r^2$. What you've calculated isn't really the volume of any particular shell, but the limit of the ratio $\frac{\text{shell volume}}{\text{shell thickness}}$, as the thickness approaches $0$.

Then you're using the fact that $\int_0^R\frac{dV}{dr}{dr}=V(R)-V(0)$. You've basically just taken a derivative followed by an antiderivative.

The formula above is exact because of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). The integral is (by definition) the limit of a sequence of approximations obtained by subdividing the domain into smaller and smaller intervals (corresponding to thinner and thinner shells in your example), and it turns out that if you estimate each shell volume in this process by $\Delta V=\frac{dV}{dr}\Delta r$, then the sequence of approximate volumes approaches the exact total volume you want in the limit, because the "error" corresponding to the "erased" higher-degree terms approaches $0$.